# Tic Tac Toe (XOX) Game Algorithm How to Extract PHP with For Loop?

Tags: php, for-loop, tic-tac-toe

I explained the visual and the logic to get the desired result. Logic is based entirely on logic. How can I draw this conclusion with for loops.

[image: tic tac toe algorithm]

***The logic of the Array structure***

**Horizontal Row:**

0 1 2

1 2 3

4 5 6

5 6 7

8 9 10

9 10 11

12 13 14

13 14 15

**Vertical Column:**

0 4 8

4 8 12

1 5 9

5 9 13

2 6 10

6 10 14

3 7 11

7 11 15

**Diagonal Backslash:**

0 5 10

5 10 15

**Diagonal Forward Slash:**

3 6 9

6 9 12

**The code I tried to achieve the desired result by trying: (Not working)**

```
function generate_win_lines($grid_size) {
    $win_lines = [];

    for ($a = 0; $a < $grid_size; $a++) {
        $horizontal = []; 
        $vertical   = [];

        
        for ($b = 0; $b < $grid_size; $b++) {
                $horizontal[] = $grid_size * $a + $b;
                $vertical[]   = $grid_size * $b + $a;
        }
        
        $win_lines['Horizontal']['Row ' . ($a + 1)]  = $horizontal;
        // Add the generated column to the overall array
        $win_lines['Vertical']['Column ' . ($a + 1)] = $vertical;
        // This will append to the overall array the position of the diagonals
        $win_lines['Diagonal']['backslash'][]        = $grid_size * $a + $a;
        // This will append to the overall array the position of the diagonals
        $win_lines['Diagonal']['forward slash'][]    = $grid_size * ($a + 1) - ($a + 1);
        
    }

    return $win_lines; 
}

print_r(generate_win_lines(4));
```

**My Manual code where I got the desired result:**

```
<?php 
$win_lines['Horizontal']['Row 1'] = [ 0,1,2 ];
$win_lines['Horizontal']['Row 2'] = [ 1,2,3 ];
$win_lines['Horizontal']['Row 3'] = [ 4,5,6 ];
$win_lines['Horizontal']['Row 4'] = [ 5,6,7 ];
$win_lines['Horizontal']['Row 5'] = [ 8,9,10 ];
$win_lines['Horizontal']['Row 6'] = [ 9,10,11 ];
$win_lines['Horizontal']['Row 7'] = [ 12,13,14 ];
$win_lines['Horizontal']['Row 8'] = [ 13,14,15 ];

$win_lines['Vertical']['Column 1'] = [ 0,4,8 ];
$win_lines['Vertical']['Column 2'] = [ 4,8,12 ];
$win_lines['Vertical']['Column 3'] = [ 1,5,9 ];
$win_lines['Vertical']['Column 4'] = [ 5,9,13 ];
$win_lines['Vertical']['Column 5'] = [ 2,6,10 ];
$win_lines['Vertical']['Column 6'] = [ 6,10,14 ];
$win_lines['Vertical']['Column 7'] = [ 3,7,11 ];
$win_lines['Vertical']['Column 8'] = [ 7,11,15 ];

$win_lines['Diagonal']['backslash 1'] = [ 0,5,10 ];
$win_lines['Diagonal']['backslash 2'] = [ 5,10,15 ];

$win_lines['Diagonal']['forward slash 1'] = [ 3,6,9 ];
$win_lines['Diagonal']['forward slash 2'] = [ 6,9,12 ];

print_r($win_lines);
```

**Desired result:**

```
Array
(
    [Horizontal] => Array
        (
            [Row 1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 0
                    [1] => 1
                    [2] => 2
                )

            [Row 2] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 1
                    [1] => 2
                    [2] => 3
                )

            [Row 3] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 4
                    [1] => 5
                    [2] => 6
                )

            [Row 4] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 5
                    [1] => 6
                    [2] => 7
                )

            [Row 5] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 8
                    [1] => 9
                    [2] => 10
                )

            [Row 6] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 9
                    [1] => 10
                    [2] => 11
                )

            [Row 7] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 12
                    [1] => 13
                    [2] => 14
                )

            [Row 8] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 13
                    [1] => 14
                    [2] => 15
                )

        )

    [Vertical] => Array
        (
            [Column 1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 0
                    [1] => 4
                    [2] => 8
                )

            [Column 2] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 4
                    [1] => 8
                    [2] => 12
                )

            [Column 3] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 1
                    [1] => 5
                    [2] => 9
                )

            [Column 4] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 5
                    [1] => 9
                    [2] => 13
                )

            [Column 5] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 2
                    [1] => 6
                    [2] => 10
                )

            [Column 6] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 6
                    [1] => 10
                    [2] => 14
                )

            [Column 7] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 3
                    [1] => 7
                    [2] => 11
                )

            [Column 8] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 7
                    [1] => 11
                    [2] => 15
                )

        )

    [Diagonal] => Array
        (
            [backslash 1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 0
                    [1] => 5
                    [2] => 10
                )

            [backslash 2] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 5
                    [1] => 10
                    [2] => 15
                )

            [forward slash 1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 3
                    [1] => 6
                    [2] => 9
                )

            [forward slash 2] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 6
                    [1] => 9
                    [2] => 12
                )

        )

)
```